# How to update 2 forms with one submit button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

I have 2 forms on my page that I'm looking to update with one submit button.

I am able to successfully update each form individually, however, I haven't been able to update them concurrently using the same button.

The first form is updated via the php code located on the same page (say page1.php) that I'm putting the button.

The second form is updated via redirection to another page (let's say page2.php) where an event is called/handled (after completion, the page redirects back to page1.php where the changes can be viewed) and I achieve this using the onclick="page2.php".

I was wondering how I should go about getting both of these forms to update when I click the button.

Code example:

```
<form id="form" method="post" action="page1.php">
   <input type="submit" class="button" value="Submit" onclick="form.action=\'page2.php\';" />
</form>
```

Comment: What do you mean the form is "updated"?

Comment: Can you please post the code ?

Comment: my code would not work, deleted

Comment: @SecondRikudo the first form is filled with multiple <textarea>'s and the second is checkboxes. When I make edits to the texts and the checkboxes (check or uncheck some), only 1 of the updates can be achieved at a time

Comment: Instead of redirecting to a different page, include the php code from page2.php when you "update" form1

Comment: sorry user322.... my code would not have worked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming by updating a form, you mean submitting, **there is no way you can submit two forms at once** since you can't have two redirections at the same time (it just won't make sense).

But, one of the options is to submit the first form via an AJAX call, and if the response is correct, do the normal submit of the other form. This also makes sense since you said that you're submitting the first form to the current page you're on, which means no layout changes, etc...

Ideally, you'd make a new landing page for the AJAX call (no need to render the whole page behind the curtains) which would just output the result of whatever you're doing there (for example, updating database, and if success, just echo 'ok'). Then just check if the response is the expected one ('ok' in the case above, though you might want to return some more info, like an id or something), and if so, submit the second form regularly.

Hope this wasn't too confusing.

---

The other method I can suggest is simpler, but involves changing the app flow.

You can try to combine the two forms into a single form and just submit it to page2. It's something worth thinking about, altough it might require a lot of rewriting of the existing code.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I'm tryinig to do. Yes, by "updating" I do mean submitting, sorry for the confusion. I'll give this a try now.

Comment: You're welcome! Since I don't know what happens on each page, I can't give you a more accurate solution, but these two ideas should get you started.